# Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'image'

Tags: swift2, uiimage, ios9

In my X-Code project  thumbImg is UIImage .when i type thumbImg.image is says Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'image' . I don't know why its happening. Please help me out

I am using Xcode 7.3.1

I am adding an image of that:

[image: code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: thumImg is already declared as a UIImage

```
 thumbImg = UIImage(named: "\(self.pokemon.pokedexId)")
```

or maybe you wanted your thumbImg to be a UIImageView and not UIImage

Comment: that works bt why is says  UIImage has no 'image' member. the tutorial of I have seen  there is that image member in the UIImage.?? :(

Comment: It isnt Possible to be honest, a UIImage doesn't have an image.. it is an image itself. But you must be confusing it with UIImageView.

Comment: becuase a UIImageView does have an image, because it is a "View" that contains image